# How to prevent message dialog "myapp wants to sign using privateKey ..." on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, https, certificate, keychain

I've developed application which communicates with my own server over HTTPS. And I use .p12 certificate for mutual authorization. The problem is that after I send first request on server I receive OSX's dialog message:
[image]

I know that need to make code sign but:

Can I make some workaround/hack/trick to prevent it? Please note that my app is not going to go on Mac Store. So I could use any private API.

If we can't prevent this dialog then what should I do:
1. Code sign my application via Mac Developer Program?
2. Or make trusted my p12 certificate?

If need to make some of these items above please provide a quote as proof from Apple's documentation.

I use OSX 10.8 an later.

Answer (score 0):

Code signing your application is the most straightforward way to avoid this dialog. When importing the certificate and private key your signed application and future versions that match its designated requirement will be given access to the key for all purposes. See [Mac OS X Code Signing In Depth](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-SUBSECTION1) and the [Code Signing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/index.html) for more information.

On your development systems that have already imported the key into the keychain you may see the authorization prompt one additional time, on systems that do not yet have the key in the keychain the prompt shouldn't appear at all.

Comment: I code signed app using Mac Developer program. To be sure I checked it using: "codesign -d -r- myapp.app". But I still receive dialog on non-developer OSX. Now there I receive message "Do you want to allow access to this item?" only.